# создать плагин с выводом всех товаров в него (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

плагин не могу создать , чтобы все товары из WooCommerce выводило мне в таблицу , один столбец с названием товара, второй с артикулом , и третий с количеством на складе. Помогите кто может пожалуйста